# Camel HTTP endpoint throws NoHttpResponseException for large File bodies

Tags: java, http, apache-camel

Attempting to upload files onto a Server using its REST API from a Camel endpoint.
Below is part of the camel Endpoint in consideration

```
<camel:setBody>
 <camel:simple>${header.objectdata.getData}</camel:simple><!-- 2mb file as String -->
</camel:setBody>
<camel:setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
 <camel:constant>PUT</camel:constant>
</camel:setHeader>
<camel:recipientList id="ml-rest">
  <camel:simple>{URL_HERE}</camel:simple>
</camel:recipientList>
```

The above endpoint works fine with smaller files. But for the ~2mb file, it throws

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException: The server localhost failed to respond
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1976)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)...
```

I tried uploading the same file onto the server using POSTMAN(not via code,camel) and it works fine.

Tried setting the SO_TIMEOUT option, but strangely it appears capped to 30 seconds. Setting values less than 30 appears to work, but greater than 30 seconds are simply ignored. I noticed this based on the time difference between the occurences of the following log statements.

```
...
[t1] Request body sent
[t2] Closing the connection
```

Comment: Most likely persistent connections that are kept alive by the connection manager become stale. That is, the target server shuts down the connection on its end without HttpClient being able to react to that event, while the connection is being idle, thus rendering the connection half-closed or 'stale, try use chunking.

Comment: Hey Fady! Added Transfer-Encoding=chunked, but sadly doesn't help.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And have you tried using camel-http4 instead

Comment: Am using Camel version 2.19.0. Yes I did try with camel-http4 only to yield the same erroneous results.